# Buffered file reading in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have following Dart code and I am trying to make reading the file buffered. Just like Java's `BufferedReader` or C++ `ifstream`. Is there such functionality? I cannot even find buffer mentioned in `file.dart` nor `file_impl.dart`. If I understood my debugging correctly, it seems that Dart is reading the whole file at once.

So could anybody help me make it buffered or point me in right direction where the buffer is?

```
final file = File(join(documentsDirectory, "xxx.txt"));
final List<String> lines = await file.readAsLines(); //file.readAsLinesSync()
lines.forEach((line) {
    ....
});
```

Comment: use [LineSplitter](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-convert/LineSplitter-class.html) instead

Comment: @pskink Yes. But the speed doesnt matter to me. I wanted buffer with variable size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file.openRead()`. This will return a `Stream` of bytes. If you want to read as characters, `transform` the stream using the appropriate decoder (probably `utf8`).

As it says, you must read the stream to the end, or cancel it.

Comment: Alright, thanks. That seems as solution for now. 
Am I correct in thinking it has buffer of size `_blockSize = 64 * 1024` which cannot be changed?

Comment: I've observed before that it seems to use 64k, yes. I've never has the need to change it.

Comment: could you look at my edit, if you have answer for that too?

Comment: Are you in release mode or debug mode? It will make a big difference.

Comment: The source code of `readAsLines` is available in `file_impl.dart`, so you should be able to experiment with the two different approaches.

Comment: Yes, i know. I have file 1MB. ReadAsLines() = 0.4s, stream = 0.8s. Thats double as opposed to Kotlin BufferReader(1 * 1024 * 1024) = 0.80, Kotlin BufferReader(64 * 1024) = 0.83. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Never mind. It is `await for` which made the speed a lot worse. Accepting your answer.